# get an element from array with http GET php

Tags: php, html, xml, xslt

I'm using a form in a html document an I have this input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="codigo">
   <xsl:attribute name="value">
       <xsl:value-of select="codi"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
</input>
```

For example if I press the submit button in the URL I see: `?codigo=4`, in my php code I am adding a child "comentario" in a document.xml for a select finca:

```
$finca = $fincas->finca[$_GET['codigo']]->comentarios->addChild('comentario');
```

The question is that my server can not process the $_GET parameter into an array and I need to add the child in a specific finca. I tried to do it with a fixed parameter like '1' and it's working.

Is there any solution to solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you amend your question by posting the kind of datastructure you were hoping to generate, or the kind of datastructure you were hoping to see in $_GET (or $_POST)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, after looking a long time I found a very easy solution, is to do a Parse int, (int)